# Matrix Representations and Similar Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a doubt about the following question:[image]

I understand how to do part (a), but for part (b), I'm not sure how to guarantee a solution for P. I made lots of equations and when I'm starting to bash it out. It's really getting messy and its really mistake-prone. Could someone tell me how to solve this and maybe where to get some more questions of the same topic? Thanks

Comment: Part (b) is about a change of coordinate, or basis, matrix. That is, $P$ is a matrix representation of the identity transformation, so it is invertible. See section 2.5 in Linear Algebra, where $P$ is $Q$ in their notation https://anujitspenjoymath.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/stephen_h-_friedberg_2c_arnold_j-_insel.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you did question (a), you should have found the matrices $P_1,P_2$ such that
$$A_1= P_1^{-1}T P_1, \, A_2= P_2^{-1}T P_2$$ where $A_1,A_2$ are the matrix representations of $T$ in the basis $B_1,B_2$.

Then

$$A_1=\left(P_2^{-1}P_1\right)^{-1} A_2 \left(P_2^{-1}P_1\right)$$ and therefore the $P$ you’re looking for is

$$P=P_2^{-1} P_1$$